# Tableview not refreshing from core data (Swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, core-data

I have a tableview with a search bar that allows the user to search for a timezone. Once they select a timezone it's saved to core data, the search controller is dismissed and the tableview should refresh to show saved timezones and current weather conditions.

The data is being fetched from a third party api.

The issue is that the tableview is not (reliably) refreshing once the data is saved to core data and the search controller is dismissed. I can see that the data is being saved in the console.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TimeZonesTable: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var cities: [Zone] = []
    var filteredCities = [Zone]()
    var savedCities: [SavedCity] = [] {
        didSet {
            refreshData()
        }
    }

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    var isSearchBarEmpty: Bool {
        return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

    var isFiltering: Bool {
        return searchController.isActive && !isSearchBarEmpty
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        getAvailableCities()
        getSavedCities()

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.label

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self // Monitor when the search button is tapped.
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a city"
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false


        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            // For iOS 11 and later, place the search bar in the navigation bar.
            navigationItem.searchController = searchController

            // Make the search bar always visible.
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        } else {
            // For iOS 10 and earlier, place the search controller's search bar in the table view's header.
            tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        }          
    }

    func getAvailableCities() {

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")!

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

            // Check for errors
            guard error == nil else {
                print ("error: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            // Check that data has been returned
            guard let content = data else {
                print("No data")
                return
            }

            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let fetchedData = try decoder.decode([Zone].self, from: content)

                for city in fetchedData {
                    self.cities.append(city)
                }

            } catch let err {
                print("Err", err)
            }
        }
        // Execute the HTTP request
        task.resume()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if isFiltering {
            return filteredCities.count
        }
        return savedCities.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timeZoneCell") as! TimeZoneCell

        if isFiltering {

            if let city = filteredCities[indexPath.row].cityName {

                if let country = filteredCities[indexPath.row].countryName {
                    cell.cityName.text = "\(city.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: " ")), \(country)"
                    cell.cityDate.text = ""
                    cell.currentCityTime.text = ""
                    cell.currentTemp.text = ""
                    cell.weatherIcon.image = nil
                }
            }
        } else {

            let city = savedCities[indexPath.row]

            if let city = city.cityName {

                cell.cityName.text = "\(city)"

                if let date = savedCities[indexPath.row].formattedDate {

                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    let formattedDate = formatter.date(from: date)

                    formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, d MMM"
                    let dateString = formatter.string(from: formattedDate!)

                    cell.cityDate.text = dateString
                }

                if let time = savedCities[indexPath.row].formattedTime {

                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
                    let formattedTime = formatter.date(from: time)

                    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
                    let timeString = formatter.string(from: formattedTime!)

                    cell.currentCityTime.text = timeString
                }
            }
            cell.currentTemp.text = String(city.currentTemp.rounded().formatted)
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if isFiltering {

            let selectedCity = filteredCities[indexPath.row]
            let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
            let originalUrl = "http://vip.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=\(apiKey)&format=json&by=city&city=\(selectedCity.cityName!)&country=\(selectedCity.countryCode!)"

            if let encodedUrl = URL(string: originalUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)!) {

                let task = session.dataTask(with: encodedUrl) { data, response, error in

                    // Check for errors
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print ("error: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }
                    // Check that data has been returned
                    guard let content = data else {
                        print("No data")
                        return
                    }

                    do {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                        let fetchedData = try decoder.decode(TimeZones.self, from: content)

                        if let city = fetchedData.zones?.first {

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {

                                    let savedCity = SavedCity(context: context)

                                    if let offSet = city.gmtOffset {

                                        savedCity.formattedDate = city.formatted!.components(separatedBy: " ").first!
                                        savedCity.formattedTime = city.formatted!.components(separatedBy: " ").last!
                                        savedCity.formatted = city.formatted
                                        savedCity.countryCode = city.countryCode
                                        savedCity.formattedCityName = city.zoneName!.components(separatedBy: "/").last!
                                        savedCity.countryName = city.countryName
                                        savedCity.gmtOffset = Int32(offSet)
                                        savedCity.zoneName = city.zoneName
                                        savedCity.cityName = city.cityName

                                    }
                                    // Save to core data
                                    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.saveContext()
                                    self.searchController.isActive = false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch let err {
                        print("Err", err)
                    }
                }
                // execute the HTTP request
                task.resume()
            }
        }
    }

    func didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
        getSavedCities()
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!)
    }

    // Filter results based on search text
    func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {

        filteredCities = cities.filter ({$0.cityName?.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil})
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func getSavedCities() {
        if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
            if let timeZonesFromCD = try? context.fetch(SavedCity.fetchRequest()) {
                if let timeZones = timeZonesFromCD as? [SavedCity] {
                    savedCities = timeZones
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func refreshData() {

        for city in savedCities {

            let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
            let refreshUrl = "http://vip.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=\(apiKey)&format=json&by=city&city=\(city.cityName!)&country=\(city.countryCode!)"
            let weatherUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=\(city.cityName!),\(city.countryCode!)&units=metric&appid=\(apiKey)"

            if let encodedWeatherUrl = URL(string: weatherUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)!) {
                if let encodedRefreshUrl = URL(string: refreshUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)!) {

                    // Refresh time an date
                    let refreshTask = session.dataTask(with: encodedRefreshUrl) { data, response, error in

                        // Check for errors
                        guard error == nil else {
                            print ("Refresh error: \(error!)")
                            return
                        }
                        // Check that data has been returned
                        guard let content = data else {
                            print("No data")
                            return
                        }

                        do {
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                            let fetchedData = try decoder.decode(TimeZones.self, from: content)

                            if let data = fetchedData.zones?.first {

                                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                    // Update time and date
                                    city.formatted = data.formatted
                                    city.formattedDate = data.formatted!.components(separatedBy: " ").first!
                                    city.formattedTime = data.formatted!.components(separatedBy: " ").last!
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                        } catch let err {
                            print("Refresh error", err)
                        }
                    }
                    // Refresh current weather
                    let weatherTask = session.dataTask(with: encodedWeatherUrl) { data, response, error in

                        // Check for errors
                        guard error == nil else {
                            print ("Weather error: \(error!)")
                            return
                        }
                        // Check that data has been returned
                        guard let content = data else {
                            print("No data")
                            return
                        }

                        // Decode data

                        do {
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                            let currentWeatherData = try decoder.decode(Zone.Weather.self, from: content)

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                if let weather = currentWeatherData.list {

                                    if let temp = weather.first?.main?.temp {
                                        if let icon = weather.first?.weather?.first?.icon {

                                            city.icon = icon
                                            city.currentTemp = temp
                                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch let err {
                            print("Weather error", err)
                        }
                    }
                    // execute the HTTP request
                    refreshTask.resume()
                    weatherTask.resume()
                }
            }
        }
        print(savedCities)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "not reliably refreshing"? does it just show the wrong time/date/weather in cells or are there missing cities? maybe you want to post a screenshot to illustrate your problem

Comment: The city names show but the time/date/weather doesn’t show except for the most recently added city. This happens most times but occasionally it refreshes as expected. I think the issue is when I’m reloading the table after refreshing the data from the API.

Comment: I’ve added a screenshot